# Unsupported field datatype: wysihtml5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin, wysihtml5

I have rails_admin backend and am using

```
gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails'
```

In config/initializers/rails_admin.rb I have following field description

```
config.model Article do
    edit do
      field :detail_text, :wysihtml5
    end
  end
```

After this I get the following error in my admin area:

```
Unsupported field datatype: wysihtml5
```

Rails: 3.2.3
Ruby: 2.0.0

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you run bundle install?

Comment: yes, of course I ran it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am used another gem and it works fine

```
gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails'
```

and wrote in rails_admin.rb

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model Team do
    edit do
      field :description, :text do
        bootstrap_wysihtml5 true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

see https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Text

Answer (score 0):

I have ckeditor with rails_admin and i installed it from

1. i just add and install according to this url https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor
2. gem 'ckeditor' before rails_admin gem
3. in config/initializers/rails_admin.rb file

```
config.model YourModel do
    edit do
      field :description do
        ckeditor { true }
      end
    end
 end
```

It will work.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I found an answer, right gem was: 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails'. see my answer